# JQuery submit form Multiple times/

Tags: php

I have 2 forms on one page. One to upload image and other to upload specification.

**Problem**
I'm facing an issue with my Ajax request which sent form request multiple times.
If I click 'upload Image', it will upload same image like few times. It will cashe the click event and add it to new event every time.

I tried fixing this using `.unbind()`; it works **However, If I click upload specification, it will run the upload image request**. So .Unbind() didn't work.

How I can fix this please. So right ajax request is sent only once.

Here is code for my image upload.

```
    //IMAGE UPLOAD
     $(document).unbind('submit').bind('submit', "#UploadImage",function() {

         event.preventDefault();

         var customerId = $(this).parent().find('input[name="customerId"]').val();
         var image = $(this).parent().find('input[name="image"]').val();

       //send ajax request
       jQuery.ajax({
         url: "../data/stock.php?action=stock-image-upload",
         type: "POST", 
         data: new FormData(this), 
         processData: false, //prevent jQuery from converting your FormData into a string
         contentType: false,
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
         console.log(2);
             $('.image-viewer-modal').modal('hide');
            var filter = "<?php echo $id_stc ?>";
            var tab_content_to_change = "#stock-sub-list";
            jQuery(tab_content_to_change).load('/tasks/stock/stock-list.php?filter='+filter);


         },
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           //Display error message to user
           alert("An error occured when saving the data");
         }
    }); 
});
```

Here is specification upload.

```
  //specification UPLOAD
     $(document).unbind('submit').bind('submit', "#Uploadspecification ",function() {

         event.preventDefault();

         var customerId = $(this).parent().find('input[name="customerId"]').val();
         var specification = $(this).parent().find('input[name="specification "]').val();

       //send ajax request
       jQuery.ajax({
         url: "../data/stock.php?action=stock-specification -upload",
         type: "POST", 
         data: new FormData(this), 
         processData: false, //prevent jQuery from converting your FormData into a string
         contentType: false,
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
         console.log(2);
             $('.image-viewer-modal').modal('hide');
            var filter = "<?php echo $id_stc ?>";
            var tab_content_to_change = "#stock-sub-list";
            jQuery(tab_content_to_change).load('/tasks/stock/stock-list.php?filter='+filter);


         },
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           //Display error message to user
           alert("An error occured when saving the data");
         }
    }); 
});
```

**How I can clear the submit event so every time I click on upload button, right ajax request is sent only once**

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try with Async:false
or other end you can click none of a event after click at once

Comment: I just tried that, it still sends more than one request.